# Error reading azurerm_backup_protected_file_share - BMSUserErrorCrossRegionRestoreNotEnabledInThisVault

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to read a backup-protected file share in Azure using the `azurerm_backup_protected_file_share` resource in my Terraform script. However, when I try to execute the script, I get the following error message:

```
Error: BMSUserErrorCrossRegionRestoreNotEnabledInThisVault: Cross region restore is not enabled for the backup vault <vault_name>.
```

I have double-checked that the backup vault exists and that the file share is protected by a backup policy in the vault. I have also confirmed that the credentials I am using to authenticate with Azure have the necessary permissions to access the backup vault.

What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: I was thinking that this can be related with the issue raised on github https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/21663

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the verion of your provider .

I have following azurerm provider version and it worked.

***Providers.tf***

```
azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      //version = "=3.0.2"
      version = "=3.50.0"
       
    }
```

***Code:***

```
resource "azurerm_backup_container_storage_account" "protection-container" {
  resource_group_name = xxxx
  recovery_vault_name = xxxx
  storage_account_id  = xxx
}

resource "azurerm_backup_policy_file_share" "example" {
  name                = "tfexxxxpolicy"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  recovery_vault_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vault.name
  

  backup {
    frequency = "Daily"
    time      = "23:00"
  }

  retention_daily {
    count = 10
  }
}

resource "azurerm_backup_protected_file_share" "share1" {
  
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  recovery_vault_name       = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vault.name
  source_storage_account_id = azurerm_backup_container_storage_account.protection-container.storage_account_id
  source_file_share_name    = azurerm_storage_share.example.name
  backup_policy_id          = azurerm_backup_policy_file_share.example.id

}
```

[image]

Comment: That's correct. I hardcoded my provider version to  "=3.54.0" and it works fine.